# Google Script (фильтрация)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работает метод `getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria()`.

Требуется скрыть только пустые значения. Но выполнение метода всячески выдает следующее:

> We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again.

Эта ошибка возникает при выполнении:

```
ss.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, null);
```

В документации гугл написано, что это аналогично методу `ss.getFilter().removeColumnFilterCriteria(columnPosition)`.

Answer (score 0):

Аналогично выдает при:

```js
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .setHiddenValues([null])
  .build();
  ss.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(2, criteria);
```

Разобрался. Если кому понадобится: вместо null поставить двойные кавычки ""
Очень странно, что null не работает, ведь в документации написано его использовать.

Comment: Нет ничего странного. `null`, как можно догадаться из документации по js, является типом данных. А Таблицы содержат в ячейках ограниченный список типов данных: `string`, `object` (`new Date()`), `number`, `boolean`. Т.о. самым "пустым" значением является пустая строка. `null` не используется вообще.